# Compare and select Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have 2 excel worksheets. On one sheet (sh1) I have column B with dates and column D:I with numbers.

I want to have a macro that, in case one of the cells in the column range D:I contains the value "2", clicking that cell gets the date value that belongs to the row of that cell and compares is to the date values in my other sheet (sh2).

The date values in the second sheet are in the B column as well.

What I have so far:

```
    Option Explicit

    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

      Dim Date1 As Date
      Date1 = Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Value

      If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Selection.Value = 2 Then
          If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:I")) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox Date1
          End If
        End If
      End If

   End Sub
```

This code already assigns a variable to the date of the row that belongs to the cell being clicked. I am stuck on the part where I compare that variable to the dates in the second sheet.

Ultimately, I want to make it so when it finds a match in the second sheet, it selects that row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code modified:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Date1 As Date

    Date1 = Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Value

    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Selection.Value = 2 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:I")) Is Nothing Then
            foundDate = Date1
            Call findDateOnSheet2
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

and (a possible solution of) what you need to find the row on sheet2:

```
Option Explicit
Public foundDate As Date

Sub findDateOnSheet2()
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    Do While Sheets(2).Cells(i, 2).Value <> ""
        If Sheets(2).Cells(i, 2).Value = foundDate Then
            Sheets(2).Activate
            Sheets(2).Rows(i).Select
            Exit Do
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

**EDIT1:**

probably your sheets look different than my testsheets. You should modify the startvalues, and/or other parameters in my code according to your sheets' structure

my first sheet:

[image: My sheet1]

and the second

[image: My sheet2]

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. I made a new module (Module1) containing the sub FindDateOnSheet2. Calling it from the Worksheet_SelectionChange sub using `Application.Run "Module1.findDateOnSheet2"` but nothing happens..

Comment: you don't need `Application.Run "Module1.findDateOnSheet2"`. If you overwrite your code with my Worksheet_SelectionChange`(...)` and create a module with my `findDateOnSheet2()` as you wrote. Then you just have to click on a cell on your first sheet. If you click on a number 2, it automacally selects the row where it finds the selected date.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. If I put a watch on the foundDate variable it says that the value for that variable is out of range.

Comment: I edited my answer and showed you my sheets... I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I figured it out once I started fiddling around with the i variable, I had to set it to 3 since I had 2 irrelevant rows above the actual data.